# How to set div width using ng-style

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I am trying to set the div width dynamically using `ng-style` but it is not applying the style. Here is the code:

```
<div style="width: 100%;" id="container_fform" ng-controller="custController">
    <div style="width: 250px;overflow: scroll;">
        <div ng-style="myStyle">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

var custController = MyApp.controller('custController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myStyle="width:'900px';background:red";

});
```

What am I missing?

Fiddle link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rameshramamoorthy/344vF/)

Answer (score 141):

The syntax of `ng-style` is not quite that. It accepts a dictionary of keys (attribute names) and values (the value they should take, an empty string *unsets* them) rather than only a string. I think what you want is this:

```html
<div ng-style="{ 'width' : width, 'background' : bgColor }"></div>
```

And then in your controller:

```js
$scope.width = '900px';
$scope.bgColor = 'red';
```

This preserves the separation of template and the controller: the controller holds the semantic values while the template maps them to the correct attribute name.

Comment: Dictionary of Keys.... made me smile. What an eloquent description for just another JS object.

Answer (score 35):

`ngStyle` accepts a map:

```
$scope.myStyle = {
    "width" : "900px",
    "background" : "red"
};
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7veB2/)**</kbd>