# Angular ngStyle value change does not apply to the DOM

Tags: angularjs

For example:

```
<ul id= "scroller" data-ng-style="{'width': {{competitors.length * 114}} + 'px'}">
```

At first competitors array have two elements, the width is `228px;` then the array has six elements, the width shown in `data-ng-style` is `668px`, but actually the width is still `228px`, why?

```
    app.controller('intelligenceController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http)  {
    $scope.competitors = [
        {
            "competitorId": "excellent",
        },
        {
            "competitorId": "average",
        }
    ];
    $scope.sumCompetitors = function(customList) {
        if (0 === customList.length) {
            $scope.competitors = $scope.competitors.concat({
                "competitorId": "none",
            });
        } else {
            $scope.competitors = $scope.competitors.concat(customList);
        }
    };
    $http.get('./listCompetitors.json').success(function(competitorsList) {
        if (false === competitorsList.hasError && 0 === competitorsList.content.code) {
            $scope.sumCompetitors(competitorsList.content.data);
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20287315/1264950) may help. Basically, you probably want to move the logic for generating the width into a single scope variable (for instance `$scope.width`), then set width in your template to `"{ 'width': width + 'px' }"`

Comment: yes, the json obeject has 4 elements.

Comment: diry check is working, the value in ngstyle is right, but the DOM doesn't change. I tried $watch and $apply, the console shows:$digest already in progress

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is there any CSS rule with !important flag override your ng-style?

Comment: @BenjaminWhite your advice helps!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are using "concat"

The concat does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Angular is "watching" and has a reference to the original array here:

```
$scope.competitors = [
    {
        "competitorId": "excellent",
    },
    {
        "competitorId": "average",
    }
];
```

When you use "concat" you are changing that reference to a new one because concat does not modify the existing array, it returns a new one.

You need to push to your existing array.

Comment: why at last data-ng-style="{'width': 668 + 'px'}" not {'width': 228 + 'px'}?

Comment: the ng-style tag will be updated correctly, but the digest loop is not going to be triggered because its watching on changes on the old array. the digest loop will update the view (what you see)

Comment: I tried push elements, the result is the same..the value in ng-style is right, however the actual value is still 228px.

Comment: Make sure you dont have any "re-assignment" like this: $scope.competitors = (something)

Comment: I found using concat is the same ,I changed html: <ul id= "scroller" data-ng-style="{'width': width}">,then after concat: $scope.width = ($scope.competitors.length * 114) + 'px';

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using an old version of angular.js, may be v1.0.8 or below.

Try replace the `{{ .. }}` in the `ng-style` with `( .. )` like this:

```
<ul id="scroller" data-ng-style="{'width': (competitors.length * 114) + 'px'}">
```

or if possible, you could upgrade the angular to be 1.2.x to use your original syntax.

**Edit:** I've just found that the `{{ .. }}` syntax will works only for the first time even in 1.2.x. If the expression has been changed, nothing happens. Therefore, you have to change to use `( .. )` instead.

Comment: Did you try the `(..)` syntax?

Comment: What if I want to know when the width of ul changes, cause at that time I can new a scroller.

Comment: You may have to use `$scope.$watch` on the expression, so it is a good idea to store the value in `$scope.witdh`, like @BenjaminWhite sugguested, and watch it instead.