# Migrating Conditional Styling From jQuery to AngularJS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I'm making my first Angular app and am struggling with the thought processes behind conditionally styling the DOM in AngularJS.

I was previously doing this in jQuery like so:

`containerWidth = lineWidth / numberOfObjects;
$container.css('width',containerWidth);`

So if there's 1 object the width is 100% and if there are 5 the width becomes 20%.

I'm unsure whether to do this in link, inside a directive or in the controller itself?

Comment: DOM manipulation is basically done in Directive, However, you can use jquery syntax inside controler. eg .$("your selector").css() in controler

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287241/how-to-set-div-width-using-ng-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Example:

```
<div ng-style="divStyle" />
```

and JS:

```
$scope.divStyle = {'width' : (lineWidth / numberOfObjects) + 'px;' };
```

(I don't know where lineWidth comes from... but that's the idea)

Comment: Does the JS part go in the controller?

Comment: Yes, the controller that renders the part of the view you're interesting in dynamically styling